# R Knitting with jsonlite - works in R Markdown but not during Knitting

Tags: json, r, knitr

I got a successful knitted document from my R Mark down.  Then I modified two cells that are completely unrelated to the error.  Suddenly, I am getting an issue with my second call to jsonlite tripping up the knitting process as shown in this error:

```
line 165:  Error in open.connection(con, "rb"): Couldn't connect to server 
Calls: <anonymous ... fromJSON_String -> parseJSON -> parse_con -> open -> 
open.connection
```

Checking the source code, an earlier cell has a function that makes the json call.  Cell one that tests the function knits fine.  Cell two that re-uses the function in a loop to make a bunch of json calls (with 3.7 second delay between them) is not knitting.  The code works.  And even knitted previously.  Now it throws an error.

My gut feeling is this is a random performance issue but it now fails repeatedly and the behavior defies logic to me.  I can run the code and it works fine in every cell.  I have checked my cell declaration syntax looking for glitches that can trip up knitting and I can't find anything wrong.  The code is too big to present in its entirety here, so below is just the relevant cells from the markdown doc, the one that works when knitting (that has jsonlite in it) and the cell immediately after it that triggered the knitting error even though the code works fine.

The document now won't knit to get my latest changes.  Any ideas or helpful suggestions on how to shake out the kinks to reknit this document would be appreciated:

This cell runs and knits fine:

````
```{r p5jLiteAns, message=FALSE, warning=FALSE}
# sample ids: tt0120737, tt0468569

library(curl)
library(jsonlite)

get_json_movieRecord <- function(movieID, showRequest=FALSE) {
  movieURL_start <- "http://www.omdbapi.com/?i="
  movieURL_end <- "&plot=short&r=json&tomatoes=true"
  moovURL <- paste0(movieURL_start, movieID, movieURL_end)
  if (showRequest == TRUE) {
    print(paste("Sending request: ", moovURL)) 
  }
  as.data.frame(jsonlite::fromJSON(moovURL), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
}

# build initial data frame from first record:
movE_data <- get_json_movieRecord(IMDB_mvIDs[1,], TRUE)
movE_data[ ,1:6]
print(paste0("Num Cols: ", NCOL(movE_data)))

```
````

This cell triggers the error.  Line 165 correlates to the line that begins the for loop, so it is probably choking on the function call that makes the json call within it:

````
```{r p5getDatawDelay}

for (i in 2:250) {
  # declared ahead of the loop and then added to within the loop
  # in theory, this should yield better performance:

  movE_data <- rbind(movE_data, get_json_movieRecord(IMDB_mvIDs[i,]))
  if (i %% 2 == 0) {   # Add delay to every other request ...

    cDelayRtn <- causeDelay(3.7)

  }
}

write.csv(movE_data, file='IMDB_Top250_OMDB_Detailed.csv')
movE_data[1:6, 1:6]
paste0("Number Rows: ", NROW(movE_data))
paste0("Number Cols: ", NCOL(movE_data))

```
````

For completeness... the above code makes a function call to an earlier cell that has this delay function within it:

````
```{r p5addTimeDelayFunc, echo=T, eval=T}

causeDelay <- function(x, showDelay = FALSE)
{
  p1 <- proc.time()
  Sys.sleep(x) # nothing happens for x seconds
  if (showDelay == TRUE) {
    proc.time() - p1
  }
} 
print("Text")
causeDelay(3.7, TRUE)
print("Text after delay.")
print("")
print("Text2")
causeDelay(3.7)
print("Text after delay.")

```
````

Answer (score 1):

I think I may see the answer here.  I got the same error on 2 or 3 knitting attempts and as each one takes more then 10 minutes to hit the point of error, this is not a process you want to re do many times.  But after making a superficial edit (deletion of comments), hitting the knit button again resulted in a new error, something different than what is shown in this post.

The full code of this markdown document would take a good hour or more to click through and re-run every cell + time to re-knit.  Even though every cells was run from a previous successful attempt (and the output is still visible in the markdown document), I now suspect that something is no longer properly cached.  The solution is probably do just that: re-run every cell and then re-try the RStudio knit button again.

If anyone knows something else to try in situations like these, please do post.  Otherwise, I am looking at a lengthy process I will initiate later after I catch up on some other work.

Comment: Often, if I have extremely lengthy operations that I can afford to do "outside of" knitting (and don't want to mess with caching), I'll save the resulting objects to a .Rdata file.  Then I'll call `load("thingy.Rdata")` in a code chunk.  It's a little duct-tapey, but has saved me a lot of time and headache.

Comment: Not sure how this will help with the current hic up.  If I understand your suggestion though, it could help with the future.  First I have to fix what happened by re-doing everything.  Then, once I get clean output that knits well, I should save that to an .Rdata file  Then add load() for that file to top of my code so I don't have to re-run it all again next time I want to re-knit for a minor change.  Then this should allow me to just re-run the new enhaced cells on top of the load() command and knit the results?  is that right?  If so, I will try it to prevent recurrence of the issue. Thanks

Comment: @matt-tyers - thanks for your help.  Interesting symptom:  .RDATA env file loads what is in the variables but not the files that were up when the variables got created, so, if working w/ more than one file in the env. you have to keep a file list to to with the env file.  Having a problem on this site.  People answer my questions in comments but neither upvote nor post their ideas as answers.  Because of this, my zero ratio is climbing and I may lose ability to ask questions.  Were you aware the site worked this way when u answered me in a comment without upvoting what got your attention?

Comment: Good to know - wasn't aware of the zero ratio.  I sometimes post comments when I don't have a full "solution" but only an incomplete suggestion or trick that has helped me.  Partly because I'm not claiming a full solution, partly to avoid downvotes (I've had complete, working solutions downvoted before, probably because they weren't long enough).  For as altruistic as this site appears, it's really an interesting study in incentivized human behavior.  ...I use env files when working with an MCMC engine that returns directly to R, and was hoping it could apply - you're beyond me with ext files!

Comment: Thanks so much!  I think I am out of the red.  This site is both amazing for what you can find on here and frustrating for how political it can be sometimes.  My own struggle has led me to the conclusion I need to be better about upvoting even though i often feel a caution of wanting to hold back in case a more complete or specific answer comes along.  :-)  Thanks for the compliment too.  New to R but tinkering to find the answers.  Your idea was really helpful.